# How do I convert strings stored in a cell array to numbers in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have an excel column that contains strings of either 4 or 5 characters and I want to convert them to numbers. So instead of "close" I want the cell to contain a "5". And instead of an "open" I want the cell to contain a "4"

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('test.xlsx');

instructionopen = find(strcmp(raw,'open'),2);
instructionclose = find(strcmp(raw,'close'),2);

% I will try to convert a string cell to characters and the to a number. 
open = [] 

open = [] 
open2 = []
for i = 1:numel(instructionopen)
    open = [open; char(instructionopen(i))];  
    open2 = [open2; str2num(open(i))];
end
```

I am sure my coding is not elegant, but I am basicall trying to make two arrays, one where I convert each string element to a character and then another one to convert them to numbers. The output after converting to a character though gives me a value (!) that looks like 2 Chinese characters. I must be doing somethign worng at that step.

What am I doing wrong, or how else can I achieve numbers instead of strings in those cells?

EDIT

beaker suggested a map container. I tried

```
instructions   = {'open','close'};
valueSet = [1,2];
mapObj = []

for i = 1:numel(instructionopen)
    if instructionopen(i) == 'open'
        mapObj = containers.Map(instructions,valueSet) 
    end
end
```

But the problem is that mapObj comes out empty, so I must be doing smoething wrong.

matlabbit suggested to use the length of the string. I tried

```
instructiontype = []
for h = 1:length(instructionindex)
    instructiontype = [instructiontype; length(instructionindex(h))]
end
```

but it keeps giving me the legth of 1 for element in the array. I could not find a function strlength?

EDIT2 matlabbit suggested to use cellfun(length)

```
instructionindex = find(strcmp(raw,'Instruction: ')); %gets index of cells that have "Instruction" in them
instructionindex2 = char(raw{instructionindex, 2}); %converts the content of the cells one column to the right (second column) to characters
instructionindex3 = mat2cell(instructionindex2, ones(size(instructionindex2,1),1)); %converts this to a matrix of cells
instructionindex4 = cellfun('length',instructionindex2) %finally performing the conversion to the number that represents the length of the content of each cell
```

I now get matrix of 24 doubles, but they are all fives (5)...Yet some should be fours (4).

If I had not done the mat2cell, it would have not allowed me to perform the length function, because I kept getting the error that they were not cells. Maybe because I used char before that, and I got a value that looked like closecloseclosecloseopenopencloseopenopenopenopen...ect

EDIT 3: posting a picture as an example of a simplified excel file

[image]

I am managing to extract the numbers for condition and trials but I need to have something numeric for the "open" and "close". I am trying to  convert them to the respective string length.

I also tried this:

```
instructionindex = find(strcmp(raw(:,1),'Instruction: '));
instructionindex1 = char(raw{instructionindex,2});
instructionindex2 = mat2cell(instructionindex1, ones(size(instructionindex1,1),1));
instructionindex3 = cellfun('length',instructionindex2);


test = zeros(size(instructionindex2));
for h = 1:length(instructionindex2)
    if strcmp(instructionindex2{h},'open')
        test(h) = 4;
    elseif strcmp(instructionindex2{h},'close')
        test(h) = 5;
    end
end
```

**Interestingly this gives me numbers (!)**, but the arrays consists of 0s for open and 5 for close. I guess I am fine with this for now, but I am really wondering what I am doing wrong!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) container which can map strings as keys to numeric values.

Comment: Do you want the number 5 or the text representation "5"? Also, is there a correlation with "close" having 5 characters? Is this really just a strlength operation?

Comment: Thanks @beaker for the suggestion. I edited my question with a solution I treid, but I still must be doing domething wrong..

Comment: Thanks @matlabbit! I need a number because I am afarid of all the limitations I get when I try to conacatenate whenever my cells are not numbers. The problems I have been having with these strings have really made everything so complicated. I tried somethign as you suggested, and edited my question, but it did not work..

Comment: I suspect you keep getting 1 because you are not dereferencing the cell. instructionindex(h) will return a scalar cell. instructionindex{h} will return the contents of the cell at h.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
raw = {'open','close','open','close'};
```

to get the length, starting in 16b you can do:

```
strlength(raw)
```

before 16b you can do:

```
cellfun('length',raw)
```

Not totally clear on what you're solving, but you can consider using logical indexing for assigning values:

```
raw(strcmp(raw,'open')) = {'some value'};
raw(strcmp(raw,'close')) = {pi}
```

Comment: Thank you @matlabbit!  I have Matlab R2015a. At first it did not work because I kept getting the error "cellfun works only on cells.". So then I used mat2cell first to convert it to cells and the used cellfun length. But then I get all 5s! I think I am very very close now! I have edited my question once again explaining better what I did! I would be so greatful for help, since I think I am close to the final result!

Comment: Any chance you could post sample data and the desired output? I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to solve based on code that doesn't work for you.

Comment: So sorry for that, @matlabbit! I attached some pictures and edited somethign new I tried which now gives me numbers for the two strings "open" and "close" - just not their length (which is what I intended to have).